# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Not working correctly

Tags: c#, excel

I have a Windows Form Application in VS2012 C# and I'm trying to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; in order to make an Excel spreadsheet. Whenever I try to type some code such as

```
Application _excelApp;
```

or

```
var application = new Application();
```

I keep getting the same error which is "Application is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Form.Application' and 'Microsoft.Office.Inter.Excel.Application'. I was just wondering what the solution is so I could start using the Interop.Excel. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use the fully-qualified type name (including namespaces) or use a namespace alias.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; // In your usings

var application = new Excel.Application();
```

or

```
var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```